# How can I test automatically Service Workers in offline mode? Trying with Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, service-worker

I developed some service workers but when the complex of the service workers (SW) is getting higher I want to create a tests battery to check it out regularly.

I decided to use Cypress in first instance. But I struggle with some problems that dont let me handle the situation.

1. Offline mode. Cypress has no native use case but has a recipe for Chrome (it doesnt matter if it works only in a unique browser)
2. When offline mode recipe is active the fetch doesn't work properly on the test.

[Cypress Open Issues - Simulate offline mode #235](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/235)

[Cypress Offline Mode Recipe for Chrome](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/server-communication__offline)

The same web works on the browser but not in the cypress test.

Cypress test code

```js
it('can load if sw registered and try to visit', () => {
   cy.visit(folder)
   cy.contains('#sw-status', 'SW not registered')
   cy.get('#register').click().wait(1000)
      
   Cypress.goOffline()
   Cypress.assertOffline()
      
      
   cy.get('#fetch').click()
   cy.contains('#fetch-response', '200')
})
```

Exception catched on cypress - Failed to fetch
[image: Cypress - Fetch not working. Exception]

No internet. Firefox can use the fetch
[image: Firefox Fetch Ok]

No internet. Chrome can use the fetch
[image: Chrome Fetch Ok]

Something weird. With no internet Chrome said window.navigator.onLine is true
[image: window.navigator.onLine differs Firefox/Chrome]

**Any suggestion? Try with another testing framework?**

I think the explanation of the problem is full and complete, but if someone thinks could be useful I can share code without problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I did a deeper search in the cypress issues.

I found a [comment talking about a problem in some situations when NOT using localhost as server name](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/17723#issuecomment-906152925) (I was using custom TLD with [Valet for Linux](https://cpriego.github.io/valet-linux/), so it was very related to my problem). I hope that if you are in my situation you don't need to dive in along the same process.

So I check with the new configuration and MAGICALLY all works!.

All i did is Boot up a server using localhost and then run the tests(automatically or with cypress UI)

```json
// package.json
// 'npm test' to run tests automatically
// 'npm run test:ui' to run with cypress UI 
"scripts": {
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 3030 -c-1",
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "cy:ui": "cypress open",
    "test": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3030 cy:run",
    "test:ui": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3030 cy:ui",
  },`
```

I have shared the first attempts in a repository.

[Dune Browsing - Exploring testability of service workers in offline mode.](https://github.com/raultm/dunebrowsing)